# Chaining Attacks in Mutants and Masterminds 3e?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, multiattack

So, for context, I saw a gif of a diablo like game where a spell caster  tossed a spell, hit an enemy then when the enemy died is created 2 more spell missles, and it basically propagated through a crowd of enemies until they all died.

Is there a way to do this in Mutants and Masterminds 3e? Obviously there is the Multi Attack option and i can take the penalty and just describe the power as working like the chain spell in the gif...

But, is there a way to maybe use "triggered" and some other mods to create attacks that generate from the spot of the enemy and attack the closest target or something like that?

Gif for context https://twitter.com/i/status/1725841500712427634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Minions, then the Takedown Attack 2 seems like it makes sense. Every time a minion goes down, you get another attack. Routine attacks means you can generally hit every single minion in the horde, so until one of them makes their save (possibly impossible if there's enough of a PL disparity since Minions can't get a critical success on their Toughness saves), you're just taking them down one at a time, and if they can't make the save, the GM just tells you how many you take down.

If it's meant to also work against non-minions, you might be able to work some sort of Flawed Area that stops forcing saves when someone (or maybe enough people) make their save. That would not be worth a full -1 Flaw (which would basically give you a free chance at an Area attack), but your GM might agree on a certain level of Quirk, or doing something that occasionally showed up in 2E where they allow the points of an Extra to itself be Flawed so that the Flaw only applies to the Extra (I believe the canonical 2E version had it being applied to Impervious that was Flawed to only work against Bludgeoning attacks).

Comment: I'm choosing this for the mention of minions in the first paragraph.... it would be cool if it worked on non minions, but i feel like horde games you are mostly fighting minions lol.

Answer (score 1):

Triggered 8: When you hit a close attack works well on Strength Based Attacks

alternatively a Strength Based Damage with Triggered 8: When you end a movement within 5 ft of a target + Leaping with Triggered 4: When a target within 5 ft of you ends a movement further away from you, where you can use Knockback to send them skyward, leap after them for another attack, then attack them again after you both fall to the ground, is a bit more descript and fair for some games.

Will say not many people use Triggered because its not a very well written rule and its gm dependent what you can get approved in a given game. I suggest bringing up Fast Grabs into Grab Based Strength Based Attacks with the Unarmed Descriptor being able to loop attacks into grabs back into attacks if you have enough arms via Extra Limbs, Improved Grab, and Ambidexterity. That's at least what I use to argue for general use Trigger Conditions in Heroes & Hellscapes.